# Trackpad randomly freezes

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

I have installed Loki this morning (it's awesome !).
Everything works perfectly expect my Trackpad.

**Configuration**

- Macbook Air (6.2 from 2013).
- OS : ElementaryOS Loki

**Problem**

- The trackpad/touchpad randomly freezes. I move my finger on the trackpad then suddenly it freezes, I have to remove my finger from the trackpad to unfreeze it.
- I do not have any problem when I use a mouse

**My research**

- It seems that elementaryOS uses libinput as a driver instead of synaptic.
- The trackpad works perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04 but the driver is synaptic.
- Libinput seems guilty...

**Questions**

- Have you ever face a similar problem?
- Do you have any idea to solve my issue?

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my issue on a Acer Swift 1 (SF114-32-P2PK). Running 5.0 Juno. I had to force driver to load because it would not uninstall libinput driver. I got this message when trying to uninstall libinput driver: qReading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Version 'xorg-input-tools' for 'xserver' was not found` Not sure what the reference to E: is all about... edit: I spoke to soon. After I did this initially it worked after restarting but when I restarted I still had problem. I think I need to figure out how to uninstall libinput

Comment: `E:` denotes that it is an error that will likely halt a command. Questions asked in comments are unlikely to receive answers.

Answer (score 3):

I just posted a solution for another question that might help you for this as well on:

[Way to enable vertical two-finger scrolling, but not horizontal?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7939/way-to-enable-vertical-two-finger-scrolling-but-not-horizontal/8091#8091)

I removed the libinput drivers for the touchpad and installed the synaptic drivers instead I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput libinput-tools
```

This removes libinput touchpad driver. Then install synaptics:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then restart.

This also allowed me to change Two Finger Horizontal scrolling and add palm detection (see above link) and also made the touchpad less sensitive.

I have not tested this extensively, but seems to work so far, use at your own risk. You could always remove the synaptics packages and reinstall the libinput ones if needed.

Jay

Answer (score 2):

switch to the synaptic driver:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

then force the synaptics driver to load, achieved by putting the synaptic config file into X11 directory for customisation

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```