# "Touch Pad" randomly stop working

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

First, sorry for my English.

I have a Acer-E5 574G laptop installed Elementary OS 0.4 Loki.
Sometime my touch pad will suddenly stopped working and I have to reboot my laptop to get it works again.

The touch pad is fine on Windows 10.

My laptop specs:
CPU: Intel i7 6500U
RAM: 8GB DDR3L

Touch pad driver:
Libinput

Elementary OS version:
0.4 Loki stable (up-to-date), using proprietary drivers for all components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit /etc/default/grub, and change the line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nosplash"`

To:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nomux i8042.reset quiet nosplash"`

Then from terminal execute:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should fix touchpad problems :-)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it for a few days and report back. :D

Answer (score 0):

One other option would be: Try to disabled libinput 
(as it has a lot of people have repeatedly report problems with the version that is shipped with Ubuntu and eOS) and fallback to synaptic driver:
[Trackpad randomly freezes](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7545/trackpad-randomly-freezes/7562)

The proper way to do it is:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```