# Any tips for setting up thumb rejection (MacBook Air)?

Tags: touchpad, macbook

When using a trackpad, I prefer to hover my thumb over the lower portion (as there used to be a button there!). Whenever I do that in elementaryOS, the system stops moving the cursor, and assumes I want to do a two finger gesture.

How can I configure the system to tell it to ignore my thumb at the bottom of the trackpad?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several complaints about libinput from what I can tell.  Most answers seem to recommend going back to the synaptics driver.

You can follow the directions here:

[Trackpad randomly freezes](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7545/trackpad-randomly-freezes/7562)

I followed these directions and they worked fine on my MBA.

I put the various synclient commands that suited me into my .bashrc in order to make it permanent for my user profile.  No more palm detection or errant cursor jumps while I'm typing.

Your synclient command would be:

```
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

I tested this and it does not pick up the side of my thumb anymore.