# Touchpad Locks After Inactivity Period

Tags: release-juno, touchpad, mouse, hardware, laptop

I have a Compaq 21N121AR Laptop and this is my problem: After I make a mouse movement and my finger leaves the mouse touchpad, my touchpad goes in a kind of "Sleep Mode" and it takes a few "swipes" to move again. I used the xinput list command and noticed that one of the devices dissapears (I assume it's the mouse touchpad). This is before I move my mouse, note the **virtual core pointer** part:

[image: xinput list screenshot]

This is while moving the pointer:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! It seems to be a problem with the libinput drivers, I solved my problem removing them and installing the synaptic drivers instead

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput libinput-tools
```

this removes libinput drivers, and then to install synaptic drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

And then I restarted the system and it was solved. Thanks to Jason Gambrel for posting this solution on [Trackpad randomly freezes](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7545/trackpad-randomly-freezes)